# Rewrite LockBits code without unsafe

Tags: c#, unmanaged

How to rewrite this code without unsafe modifier?

```cs
var bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
var size = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bitmap.Height;
var stream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)bmpData.Scan0, size));
```

Comment: Just use a `MemoryStream` instead of the unmanaged one

Comment: Ultimately, LockBits is about getting a pointer to raw memory - that is fundamentally an unsafe thing to be messing with. OK, it hides the void* behind IntPtr,  but it is still a pointer.

Comment: @ppetrov is there a constructor for that which takes an IntPtr?

Comment: It seems an unusual thing to want to do : point a Stream at the Scan0. Can you clarify: what are you wanting to **do** here?

Comment: Check the VB example in this post (yes, I know you asked a C# question but the VB solution uses Marshal.ReadByte on Scan0)  http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx

Comment: Are you trying to get direct read/write access to your bitmap data without copying the data to and from byte arrays?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp

Comment: You can't really use UnmanagedMemoryStream anyway, it is going to read the extra padding bytes at the end of a scanline.  So if you *really* want a stream then you'll need to derive your own class from Stream.  You could avoid unsafe code by using Marshal.Copy() to copy chunks of bytes into a byte[] buffer.

Comment: That's what the code in link i provided does, I think its the best way, I agree with Hans on Marshal.copy

Comment: @MarcGravell no there isn't, but there's still a way to use it instead. Anyway, as you said in another comment, the important thing here is to know what is Suigintou trying to do, and since I found that quite unclear I didn't try to be more specific

Answer (score 2):

To get transparent highly efficient access to the bitmap data (faster than any copy technique with LockBits), you can use the following technique which does not require to mark the code as unsafe (but it does require FullTrust):

- Create a `byte[]` for the bitmap data
- Pin it using a [`GCHandle.Alloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a95009h1.aspx) call
- Get the physical address of your `byte[]` using [`Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k4y07x3.aspx)
- Create a Bitmap object on this using [the construtor which takes an IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx)
- Do your magic on the `Bitmap` and the `byte[]`

**Important:** Try to avoid keeping objects pinned for a long time (hinders GC efficiency), and don't forget to dispose the bitmap and the GC handle in a finally clause!

You can of course also [create a normal `MemoryStream` on this `byte[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) if you need a stream.