# How do I calculate the proper size for the underlying buffer of System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I'm working with `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, and need access to individual pixels, but `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` are too slow for me.

Using [the technique described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17381303/425871), I'm allocating a `byte[]`, pinning it in memory, copying my original `Bitmap` into it, and unpinning it. I then work with the `byte[]`, and later I pin it, construct a new `Bitmap` with the buffer, and save it.

I calculate the size of the buffer in bytes as `width * height * BytesPerPixel`. I'm using `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`, so `BytesPerPixel == 4`.

This all works fine and dandy, except I apparently allocate a buffer that's too small and cause an access violation when copying the bitmap. I have to add extra space (a lot) to avoid the access violation, and everything appears to work.

**How do I calculate the proper size I need for `_buffer`?**

*EDIT:* I just discovered that the original image is `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`. However, that's 3 bytes per pixel and my buffer should be plenty large enough I would think.

Here is a complete program that demonstrates the problem. `ExtraSpace` controls the extra bytes I have to allocate...:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FastImageTest
{
    class FastImage
    {
        private const int BytesPerPixel = 4;
        private readonly byte[] _buffer;
        private readonly int _width;
        private readonly int _height;
        private const int ExtraSpace = 0;// 1024 * 1024 * 256;

        public FastImage(Bitmap from)
        {
            _width = from.Width;
            _height = from.Height;
            _buffer = new byte[_width * _height * BytesPerPixel + ExtraSpace];
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(_buffer);
            try
            {
                var address = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(_buffer, 0);
                var bitsPerPixel = 32;
                var stride = bitsPerPixel * _width;
                var pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
//***** Access violation occurs on next line
                using (var fastBitmap = new Bitmap(_width, _height, stride, pixelFormat, address))
                {
                    using (var fastBitmapGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(fastBitmap))
                        fastBitmapGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(from, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var original = new Bitmap(@"d:\pic.jpg");
            var fast = new FastImage(original);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for the info, I'll check into those things. I don't think my stride calculation is wrong, that's `BytesPerPixel`, not `Bits`. And thanks for the link to MVCE. This is a complete example, I just wasn't aware it would not necessarily be reproducible without the original image.

Comment: `var stride = bitsPerPixel * _width` where `var bitsPerPixel = 32`. That's wrong.

Comment: Ah yeah I see that now! Sorry..

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're right, the stride was my problem. I was so sure in my comment that I was using `BytesPerPixel`. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that Windows bitmap objects require the stride to be DWORD (4-byte) aligned. 24 bit images with a width not a multiple of 4 will have a stride different from 4 * width.

Also note that the stride is in bytes, not bits, so your calculation is wrong in any case. You're telling the `Bitmap` class it has a stride of `32 * width`, which is 8 times as large as it should be, so the GDI+ will run out of valid memory address possibly as early as 1/8th into the image (if you're lucky…if you're not, it'll write random data into somewhere important).

Here is what the calculation should look like:

```
int stride = 4 * ((_width * bytesPerPixel + 3) / 4);
```

Note `bytesPerPixel` instead of `bitsPerPixel`. Make sure this is calculated correctly based on the bitmap format, not just a const set to 4.

Comment: The fours aren't needed in the calculation, they cancel out. Thanks!

Comment: @Steve: you are mistaken. The fours are absolutely required and because of the way integer division works in C# (and pretty much every other mainstream programming language), they do not cancel each other out. Try some examples yourself. If `_width` is 1 and `bytesPerPixel` is 3, what is the value of `4 * ((_width * bytesPerPixel + 3) / 4)`? And what is the value of `_width * bytesPerPixel + 3`? I assure you, the result is not the same for both expressions, and only the first is correct.